# Getting MongoCommandException while connecting to the MongoDB | Java

Tags: java, mongodb, java-8, replicaset

I have created following mongoDB replicaSet:

```
set: rs0,
primary: localhost:27018,
secondry: localhost: 27019
MongoDB version: 4.2.3
```

When I am trying to connect to the replSet(I have tried connecting to both) using mongodb-java-driver-3.12, I am getting following Error:

````
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 2 (BadValue): 'The field 'key' for an _id index must be {_id: 1}, but got { _id: -1 }' on server localhost:27019. The full response is {"operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1581572046, "i": 1}}, "ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "The field 'key' for an _id index must be {_id: 1}, but got { _id: -1 }", "code": 2, "codeName": "BadValue", "$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1581572046, "i": 1}}, "signature": {"hash": {"$binary": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "$type": "00"}, "keyId": {"$numberLong": "0"}}}}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:175)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:303)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:259)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.sendAndReceive(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.sendAndReceive(DefaultConnectionPool.java:450)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl.execute(CommandProtocolImpl.java:72)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:226)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:269)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:131)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:123)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWriteCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:369)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWriteCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:360)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:284)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeCommand(CommandOperationHelper.java:277)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CreateIndexesOperation$1.call(CreateIndexesOperation.java:177)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CreateIndexesOperation$1.call(CreateIndexesOperation.java:172)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:530)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:492)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CreateIndexesOperation.execute(CreateIndexesOperation.java:172)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CreateIndexesOperation.execute(CreateIndexesOperation.java:72)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:213)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:182)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.createIndex(DBCollection.java:1698)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndex(DatastoreImpl.java:1110)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.processEmbeddedAnnotations(DatastoreImpl.java:1524)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndexes(DatastoreImpl.java:1185)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndexes(DatastoreImpl.java:1167)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndexes(DatastoreImpl.java:1189)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndexes(DatastoreImpl.java:286)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.ensureIndexes(DatastoreImpl.java:280)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.dao.BasicDAO.ensureIndexes(BasicDAO.java:132)
    at com.linkscreens.persistence.dao.generic.GenericMongoDao.<init>(GenericMongoDao.java:46)
    at com.linkscreens.broadcasting.dao.BroadcastHistoryDaoImpl.<init>(BroadcastHistoryDaoImpl.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    ... 71 common frames omitted
```
````

Comment: Can you connect to the replica-set from the Mongo Shell?

Comment: Yes, I am able to connect to replica-set from Mongo Shell. Also, I am using morphia as ORM in my system, org.mongodb.morphia-1.2.1

Comment: Please post the code for creating the connection.

Comment: The issue is resolved now but as morphia/mongo was expecting Indexing in Ascending order {_id:1} and I was providing indexing in Descending order {_id:-1}. Still don't understand why is that so.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late,   but I discovered that Spring data generated queries against  fields marked as @Id with automatic index creation are no go.

Say if you have field

```
@Id String foo;
```

Do not use finder

```
findByFoo(String);
```

in you repository interface.    Use

```
 findById()
```

instead -  which will do the same thing.

Spring data attempt to create index and fails on unique constraint.